# How do I merge xml files into one using PHP?

Tags: php, xslt

So Im having a bit of trouble understanding how to merge three xml files into one xml file using PHP.

Ive made a start but Im having difficulty, first off here is my xsl which separates a xml into 3 groups by country with the file names as "CD1_USA.xml", CD2_UK UK UK.xml" and "CD2_AU AU.xml":

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" name="cd-format"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each-group select="/CATALOG//CD" group-by="COUNTRY">
    <xsl:result-document href="CD{position()}_{current-group()/COUNTRY}.xml" format="cd-format">

    <CD_LIST country="{current-group()/COUNTRY}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </CD_LIST>

    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each-group>       
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now using PHP I need to merge these 3 xml into one file named "mergeFile.xml"

So Ive started to make an attempt but Im a bit lost from here because the mergeFile must have the prolog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Some guidance is appreciated from this point

**PHP**

```
<?php
// Read file 1
$xmlfilecontent = file_get_contents('CD1_USA.xml');

// Concat file 2
$xmlfilecontent .= file_get_contents('CD2_UK UK UK.xml');

//Concat file 3
$xmlfilecontent .= file_get_contents('CD2_AU AU.xml');
```

Comment: That stylesheet you have presented uses the XSLT 2/3 instruction `xsl:for-each-group` which is not supported in XSLT 1 which is the version the PHP XSLTProcessor supports. So it is not clear to me how you would use that stylesheet in the context of PHP. And of course if you don't want separate files then it seems easier to adjust the XSLT to create a sole result and not separate ones.

Comment: yes I understand that but its part of a Homework task Im having trouble with

Answer (score 0):

You should store data into `Array`.

```
<?php
    $xmlfilecontent = array();

    // Read and Insert file 1 into array
    $xmlfilecontent[] = file_get_contents('CD1_USA.xml');

    // Read and Insert file 2 into array
    $xmlfilecontent[] = file_get_contents('CD2_UK UK UK.xml');

    // Read and Insert file 3 into array
    $xmlfilecontent[] = file_get_contents('CD2_AU AU.xml');

    print_r($xmlfilecontent);
?>
```